# Get cookies from referring URL

Tags: php

I'm creating a web app that links across multiple domains. I'm using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to get which domain has referred the user to specific pages, but the cookies used in both domains are dynamically named - but the scripts will understand what to do with the cookies on both domains.

Specifically, I've got an iframe of one of the domains, embedded in the first domain - is there any way to grab the cookies of the main domain (that has the secondary domain embedded in the iframe), from the iframe domain?

Comment: Do the domains share a backend?

Comment: Generally cookies are per-domain and should not be shared across multiple domains. Is one domain a subdomain of the other, or are the two completely distinct domains?

Comment: Both different domains on different hosting providers - the one that's embedded is the 'hub' essentially, which controls multiple app systems.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pass a cookie from one domain to another. The best way is to add the referrer in the url with GET.

```
http://firstdomain.com?ref=http://seconddomain.com
```

Very simple.

Comment: It's not the referring domain name that's a problem, it's getting the cookies that are for that domain. Thank you, though.